I'm unable to concat custom middle ware with default middlewares in store configuration with redux persist and rtk query
its my store.ts file:
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage'; // defaults to localStorage for web
import {
  FLUSH,
  PAUSE,
  PERSIST,
  persistReducer,
  persistStore,
  PURGE,
  REGISTER,
  REHYDRATE
} from 'redux-persist';
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { configureStore, createAsyncThunk } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { setupListeners } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query';
import { authApi } from './services/authApi';
import adminReducer from './slices/adminSlice';
import { categoryApi } from './services/categoryApi';
import { PersistPartial } from 'redux-persist/es/persistReducer';

// Create a persist config
const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage, // Use localStorage as the default storage
  whitelist: ['admin'] // Add slices that you want to persist (e.g., 'admin')
};

// Combine reducers
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  [authApi.reducerPath]: authApi.reducer,
  [categoryApi.reducerPath]: categoryApi.reducer,
  admin: adminReducer
});

// Persist the root reducer
const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);
export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: persistedReducer,

  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      serializableCheck: false
    }).concat([categoryApi.middleware, authApi.middleware]), // Concatenate both middlewares

  devTools: true
});

// Optional, but recommended to enable refetching on focus/refocus
setupListeners(store.dispatch);

export const persistor = persistStore(store);

// Optional, but recommended to enable refetching on focus/refocus
setupListeners(store.dispatch);

// Types for store
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;

categoryApi.ts:
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react';
import { Category } from 'src/models/category_type';

export const categoryApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'category',
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: 'base_url' }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getCategories: builder.query<{categories: Category[]}, void>({
      query: () => '/categories'
    })
  })
});

export const {
  useGetCategoriesQuery
} = categoryApi;

categoryApi look like above and same authApi
I'm unable to find a solution why this error occur, i tried multiple solution but its not work
authApi and categoryApi created with createApi, fetchBaseQuery.
i try to concat rtk middleware authApi.middleware and categoryApi.middleware with default middleware
its give some type mismatch errorerror
pls help me i am very tired and thank in advance.

If categoryApi and authApi use the same "baseQuery" it is recommended to only have one apiSlice, and injecting the various endpoints into that one API. See documentation https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/code-splitting
If however you need different API slices you can try this
middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => getDefaultMiddleware()
     .concat(authApi.middleware)
     .concat(categoryApi.middleware)


thanks for reply i try this solution but its give same error
error: Tuple<[ThunkMiddleware<Partial>] is not assignable to type 'Tuple<Middlewares<Partial>]

Based on the comment in the code where you are adding the middlewares the code doesn't do what you think it does.

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: persistedReducer,

  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      serializableCheck: false
    }).concat([categoryApi.middleware, authApi.middleware]), // Concatenate both middlewares

  devTools: true
});


You are not concatenating two middlewares, you are concatenating one array of two middlewares. Pass the middlewares directly.
Example:
export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: persistedReducer,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      serializableCheck: false
    })
      .concat(
        categoryApi.middleware,
        authApi.middleware
      ),
  devTools: true
});

For more complete details for using getDefaultMiddleware and Typescript see the Official Documentation.
